# A measure of the "flatness" of log likelihood at the MLE

Tags: maximum-likelihood

Are there meaningful ways to quantify how "flat" the log likelihood function is around the MLE when the parameter has more than one dimension? In particular is the determinant of the Hessian a reasonable measure?

Comment: The determinant is not invariant with respect to reparameterization of the problem.  Thus, you cannot expect there to be any universal measure of flatness: you need to translate the "flatness" into something *meaningful for the problem.*  Looking at simultaneous confidence regions (which are typically estimated with the Hessian) might be a good place to start.

Comment: whuber's caveat notwithstanding, I do think you're on the right track: The expectation of the Hessian (i.e., the inverse Fisher-Information) is the asymptotic covariance of the (asymptotically normal) MLE, which is the main reason you can use it to construct the confidence regions whuber mentions. Its determinant is a suitable (albeit nor invariant, see above) measure of the "flatness" of the likelihood around the MLE.

Comment: @whuber, @fabians,

Comment: @whuber, @fabians,  What about using the largest eigenvalue of the hessian of -2 x loglikelihood, ( the hessian should be ideally postive definite at the mle), if largest eigenvalue is "small" in some sense, then the likelihood is flat. Also, is there a way to reduce to simultaneuous regions into one number?

Comment: That idea does not overcome the arbitrariness-of-scale objection.  For example, suppose you're estimating location and scale for a distributional family and you find that both eigenvalues are 1000.  What does this mean, pray tell?  Why, we don't even know what the units of measurement are!  Unless I give you more information, these statistics are *absolutely meaningless.*

Answer (score 4):

You might find that the [Fisher Information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information) has some properties you like.

Its the expectation that gives Fisher Information its interpretation as the 'informativeness' of a measurement.  But if you're just looking for something geometrically descriptive then your suggestion seems like a reasonable one to me.